External hard disk not being connected
I recently install Debian Stable 12.7 and it is otherwise working very well.
I tried to connect an external hard disk (I presume it will have NTFS partition).
The light on the hard disk turns on, it starts whirring but does not connect.
Following is the output of 'dmesg' command:
[  299.027072] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
[  299.030692] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
[  461.519421] usb 1-1.3.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  461.780067] usb 1-1.3.3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[  461.888648] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1a40, idProduct=0101, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  461.888656] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  461.888660] usb 1-1.3.3: Product: USB2.0 HUB
[  461.889073] hub 1-1.3.3:1.0: USB hub found
[  461.889248] hub 1-1.3.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  462.612070] usb 1-1.3.3.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  462.821973] usb 1-1.3.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=2626, bcdDevice=10.34
[  462.821981] usb 1-1.3.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  462.821985] usb 1-1.3.3.3: Product: My Passport 2626
[  462.821987] usb 1-1.3.3.3: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[  462.821989] usb 1-1.3.3.3: SerialNumber: 575832324139335238333439
[  462.871255] usb-storage 1-1.3.3.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  462.871439] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.3.3.3:1.0
[  462.871558] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  462.878172] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  463.889586] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 2626 1034 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  463.890390] scsi 6:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1034 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  463.900858] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  463.901059] scsi 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 13
[  463.904605] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[  464.912081] ..................................................................................................not responding...
[  576.243597] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  576.243607] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  576.243610] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[  578.244590] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  578.244599] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 0-byte physical blocks
[  580.245617] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[  582.246626] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[  582.246639] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  582.247059] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[  596.259393] scsi 6:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[  596.259405] scsi 6:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[  596.259435] ses 6:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device

What is the problem and how can it be solved?

The disk is not responding to commands. There's no software way to solve this; make sure the power supplied is sufficient; you might try a different external enclosure with the same disk, otherwise assume the disk is physically broken.

+1 for Power.   Try plugging it into a motherboard USB socket, I often find front-case USB sockets to not-quite have 100% power.   If the enclosure has additional external power, ensure it's on & working.

@Kingsley "it starts whirring but does not connect" I would try to procure a known-OK disk with same connectivity and compare results.
